# Magento - find categories with only disabled products

Tags: magento

I am using the code below to loop through all my 'bottom level' categories in Magento (CE 1.7.2) to find (and optionally delete) empty categories.

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/app/Mage.php";
Mage::app('admin');

$categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
   ->addFieldToFilter('level', array('gteq' => 5))
   ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
;

foreach($categoryCollection as $category) {
   if ($category->getProductCount() === 0) {
       print "delete ".$category['name']. "<br>" ;
       //$category->delete();
   }
}
?>
```

I would like to modify the code to also or alternatively find categories that only contain disabled products.

I have tried the following but it runs for 5 mins and then times out - I suspect it is not doing what I think it should be doing.

```
foreach($categoryCollection as $category)
{
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category)
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter(
    'status',
    array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED)
);
    $count = $products->getSize();
```

Can anyone advise on the correct code I could add to this loop to find categories with just disabled products.

I am not using flat product or category structures.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this.

For some reason Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED does not work - however, STATUS_ENABLED does. So by counting for each category how many products are enabled, if the count is 0 I know the cat is either empty or only has disabled products.

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/app/Mage.php";
Mage::app('admin');

$categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
   ->addFieldToFilter('level', array('gteq' => 5))
   ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
;
foreach($categoryCollection as $category)
{


$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*') //whatever attributes you want to get here
->addAttributeToFilter(
    'status',
    array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)            
);

$count = $products->getSize();

   if ($count == 0) {
       print "delete". $category['name'] ."<br>" ;        
       $category->delete();  
    }
}
```